# I don't know where I am doing mistake in this mergesort algorithm (outplace) code, can someone please see?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

The code which I mentioned is not working , while the code link which I attached which is same as mine is working perfectly for this problem :

Problem Link : [Sort An array](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-an-array/description/)

code which is working perfectly, which is same as mine : [code](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-an-array/solutions/3242535/c-mergesort/)

```
class Solution {
private: 
    // https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-an-array/solutions/3242535/c-mergesort/
    void merge(vector<int>& a, int low, int mid, int high){
        int i = low;
        int j = mid+1;
        int k = 0;
        vector<int> b(a.size(), 0);
        while(i<=mid && j<=high){
            if(a[i] <= a[j]){
                b[k] = a[i];
                i++, k++;
            }else{
                b[k] = a[j];
                j++, k++;
            }
        }
        while(i<=mid){
            b[k] = a[i];
            i++, k++;
        }
        while(j<=high){
            b[k] = a[j];
            j++, k++;
        }
        // copy b array into a array 
        i=low;
        while(i <= high){
            a[i] = b[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    void mergeSort(vector<int>& a, int low, int high){
        if(low >= high) return;
        int mid = low + ((high - low)/2);
        mergeSort(a, low, mid);
        mergeSort(a, mid + 1, high);
        merge(a, low, mid, high);
    }
public:
    vector<int> sortArray(vector<int>& nums) {
        mergeSort(nums, 0, nums.size()-1);
        return nums;
    }
};
```

I don't know where I am doing mistake, can someone please help me ?

Comment: "which is same as mine" it is not.

Comment: First line leetcode: `int i=start,j=mid+1,k=start;`. Your first line: `int i = low; int j = mid+1; int k = 0;`. Did not read more... Take time and attention to compare codes...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès giving TLE

Answer (score 1):

`int k = 0;` here is your mistake.
k should be assigned to low or i not to 0.

Comment: ok, I tried but giving TLE

Comment: I didn't want to solve it for you, the other problem would be this `vector<int> b(a.size(), 0);` merge function will be called many times, so it's not the most efficient to create it every time you call merge. so move b creation into public or sortArray and pass a reference

Answer (score 0):

***Issue***: ***temp*** variable is declared inappropriately because each recursive call to merge does not create its own temporary vector. 
***Solution:*** The ***temp*** vector has to be declared as a local variable inside the ***merge*** function in order to avoid any conflicts between different recursive calls

Final code: [click here](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-an-array/solutions/3242535/c-mergesort/comments/1928244)

Comment: in my code that is inside the merge function only

Comment: As I can see in the code at leetcode discussion (via the link you pasted), you had declared the "temp" variable as a class variable. You need to make it a function's local variable. See the correct code by clicking [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-an-array/solutions/3242535/c-mergesort/comments/1928244)